# Why does this jQuery event listener not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to setup an event listener in jQuery but can't seem to get it to work. Any tips/hints as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<script>
$('.send').on('click', function() {
    console.log('message sent');
    var text = $('.draft').val();
    Chat.send(text); 
});
</script>
<input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send">Send</button>
```

-EDIT-

When I say it doesn't work, I mean that the event handler doesn't seem to be running (console doesn't show anything when I hit the send button).

Comment: What are the symptoms? What is not working? Have you checked the javascript console for errors?

Comment: First, define "doesn't work." Second, to get the value of an input, use `.val()` as opposed to `.text()`.

Comment: code looks okay. insert `console.log('text: ' + text );` between `var text` and  `Chat.send(text);` to see what's going on in a debugger.

Comment: thanks for the comments, updated post with more details as well as .val() correction. I tried adding a console.log() statement to the event handler but nothing is showing in console still when I click the button.

Comment: Your code is working , IN every console there will tabs , for ex in firebug (clear, all, errors, warnings etc), from these select all tab you will the output @giwook

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML you have input

```
<input class="draft" type="text"/>
```

and here in jQuery, you are doing wrong `text();`

```
 var text = $('.draft').text();
```

it should be `val();`

```
 var text = $('.draft').val();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bk6eq6x/)

Edit:

Make your script DOM ready

```
//jQuery Library Always comes FIRST
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.send').on('click', function() {
        console.log('message sent');
        var text = $('.draft').val();
        Chat.send(text); 
    });
});
</script>

<input class="draft" type="text"/>
<button class="send">Send</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, updated my original question and code. Tried rerunning the new code on my machine but still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: do you happen to have jQuery library and also the above script should be after jQuery library, sometime we make mistakes by putting jQuery library in footer and try to run the script in page above footer, check your browser console log for errors too

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send">Send</button>
<script>
    $('.send').on('click', function() {
        console.log('message sent');
        var text = $('.draft').val();
        console.log(text);
        //Chat.send(text);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I cut the code out of my page; the <script> tags are in place (will update this in my original question as well) in my original code. I wish this was my problem haha.

Answer (score 0):

Event handler should be on '.send' button if you are expecting it to console when you click the button. 
`$('.send').on('click', function(){});`